# MacPro1,1 upgrade to 10.6

Tags: macos, upgrade, leopard, mac-pro

What is possible OSX upgrade for MacPro1,1 Dual-Core Intel Xeon 2.66 GHz?

Now still using using 10.5.8 (Leopard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the tech specs, you should be able to use OS X Lion (10.7) with the following specs:

- Mac computer with an Intel Core 2 Duo, Core i3, Core i5, Core i7, or Xeon processor
- 2GB of memory
- OS X v10.6.6 or later (v10.6.8 recommended)
- 7GB of available space

That would suggest to me that you would need to get onto 10.6 (Snow Leopard) + all updates and then could get to OSX Lion (10.7).

Mountain Lion+ Specifies an "early 2008 Mac Pro or newer", yours appears to be the iteration just before that.

Comment: Yes, I used Snow Leopard on my 1,1 for a long time.